# Machine learning image feature extraction

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, feature-extraction

There is a problem about feature extraction from grayscale image in machine learning.

I have a gray image converted from colored with this.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('source.png').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscalesource.png')

image2 = imread('greyscalesource.png')
print("The type of this input is {}".format(type(image)))
print("Shape: {}".format(image2.shape))
plt.imshow(image2)
```

output is :
[image]

I actually need to feature extraction from this gray picture because next part is about train a model with this feature for predict to colorized form of an image.

We can't use any deep learning library

There are some of methods such as SIFT ORB FAST...
But I really don't know how can extract features for my aim.

```
#ORB
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
#keypoints and descriptors
kpO, desO = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
img7 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kpO, 1, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv2.imwrite('_ORB.jpg',img7)
```

Output of above code is just True.

Is there any solution or idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The descriptor `des0` in your line:

```
kpO, desO = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
```

is the feature you need to use for ML algorithm.

Below is an example of Dense SIFT-based matching on a stereo image pair using  ML's knn algo:

Input Image:
[image]

Read input image and split stereo image

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def split_input_image(im):
    im1 = im[:,:int(im.shape[1]/2)]
    im2 = im[:,int(im.shape[1]/2):im.shape[1]]
    # Convert to grayscale
    g_im1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    g_im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return im1, im2, g_im1, g_im2

im = cv2.imread('../input_data/Stereo_Pair.jpg')
im1, im2, g_im1, g_im2 = split_input_image(im)
```

Write function for dense sift

```
def dense_sift(gray_im):
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    step_size = 5
    kp = [cv2.KeyPoint(x,y,step_size) for y in range(0,gray_im.shape[0],step_size)
                                      for x in range(0,gray_im.shape[1],step_size)]
    k,feat = sift.compute(gray_im,kp) # keypoints and features
    return feat, kp
```

Create an empty template image of similar dimensions to vizualize sift matches

```
visualize_sift_matches = np.zeros([im1.shape[0],im1.shape[1]])
```

Get features and key-points for gray-scale images (my order is reversed. don't get confused.)

```
f1, kp1 = dense_sift(g_im1)
f2, kp2 = dense_sift(g_im2)
```

Get matches from two feature sets using kNN

```
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(f1,f2,k=2)
```

Find common matches for a min threshold

```
common_matches = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.8 * n.distance:
        common_matches.append([m])
```

Juxtapose the two images and Connect the key-points

```
visualize_sift_matches = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(im1, kp1, im2, kp2, common_matches,
visualize_sift_matches, flags=2)
```

Visualize

```
plt.imshow(visualize_sift_matches)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I need to use these features as my input and a colored (kinda similar) image as my output to train a ml model.

Comment: So that's not exactly what I want to do. I have to use the features of the photo that I converted to gray in order to create a color photo. I have to give these features as input to the model.

Comment: you can use `des0` directly as input to your ML model. The example above is just a illustration of how it is used.

Comment: Step by step I made these, First my converted grayscale image with convert("LA") matris shape is (422,750) after use this grayscale image with ORB function, output des0 shape is (500,32).

Comment: After that, I want to train my model with this. This is an input of my model and output is colored version of my image.

Comment: The shape of colored image is (422,750,3) .  Before the train I tried to train test split to these datas but I am not also sure about that way is correct or not.

Comment: Someone said that first two values of matrix should be same , third one is unnecessary.

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I think `des0` shape `(500,32)` corresponds to 500 features of 32 dimensions each.

Comment: First two value should be same because they are width and height of image. 3rd value is for number of channels which can be 1 for grayscale, 3 for RGB and 4 for RGBA.

Comment: I am not able to fully understand your other comments. Perhaps you are trying to do something more beyond this. Ask another question on stack-overflow with more explanations. Accept this answer if your question regarding machine learning feature extraction is answered.

Comment: Okey but I want to use decisionTreeRegression and use this(500,32) feature array for input. My output is also colored version of image with shape(422,750,3). So the this is an error because of difference of shapes.

Comment: So, how should I use 500,32 feature array ? Should I convert it ? how ?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand your goal. What is your final goal? Better ask a new question with more explanations. More people will respond to a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118948/use-image-features-as-input-of-ml-model is new question. Thanks for your help, if you have any idea please help me.