# Convert gray image to colored image using feature extraction method in ML

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I have a feature array which is created from ORB with this code part:

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
#keypoints and descriptors
kpO, desO = orb.detectAndCompute(gray_image, None)
```

I create this gray image from colored one. And `des0.shape` is (500,32).
Also shape of my original image(colored one) is (422, 750, 3).

And I want to decisionTreeRegression from these arrays for predict the colored version of grayscale image which is I created from colored version.

But the problem is starting here , feature array is my input for ML model and colored image array is my output. My model predict the colored version with using this feature array and shape differences prevent this.

What should I do?

Comment: So, is your goal to convert a grayscale image to colored image using ML ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my goal

Comment: okay, please modify your question heading to reflect that. Also, add `computer-vision`, `image-processing` tags to attract right set of knowledgeable people to this question.